# Adding version number to image path? Is it possible?

Tags: html, image, version

I know it's possible to set stylesheet like this so I can refresh the cache:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=12345678" />
```

But is it possible to do the same thing with an image so I refresh the cache when image is changed but has the same name?

```
    <img src="avatar.jpg?v=23" alt="avatar" />
```

I ultimately want to use image version with meta og:image tag, because Facebook Debugger doesn't want to scrape the new image when it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Give Div Tag And Add Background Image Instead of Using Image Tag.**

And Set Background image in the external CSS file. 
And Give CSS Versioning Dynamically to : css/style.css

**Style.css**

```
.test {
     background-image: url("paper.gif");
     background-color: #cccccc;
     height:200px;
     width:200px;
     margin:10px;
     padding:10px;
}
```

**Html File: demo.html**

```
  <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>The background-image Property</h1>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <div class="test">
        </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

**My Another solution is to add in httpd-boilerplate.conf these lines:**

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/media/(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$ $1.$3 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't use the img tag tho.. The problem comes from meta og:image tag.. I am making screenshot of specific second of a video. But when I change the second and it make new screenshot, Facebook Debugger doesn't want to crawl my new image in most of the times. So I want to use ?v= with the meta og image tag because I have the specific second of the video. It's new image but the same name, because it follow the convention.